# design to allow author to edit own posts

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'd like to design a quick online sign-up web form that doesn't require a login. I ask for name and task (intranet purposes)

I'd like to allow the author of a post to edit their own entries but no one else's. I was thinking to do this based on IP address.

So if a user posts their name and task, I'll save their info plus their ip address and that's how I'll know who can edit what posts.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What if the user uses another machine, or device?

Comment: i think it should be based...on machine-names or mac address

Comment: You could use a cookie but this has the same problem if the user changes the device or clears the cookies. Are the ip addesses static? Can you use [windows authentication (intranet)](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using IPs is clearly wrong as multiple users from behind the same gateway will be seen as coming from the same IP. Cookies are better but cookies are volatile.

One of possible approaches is to assign a GUID to newly created post but in such way that only the author of the post actually gets it.

There are at least two possible ways:

- after the post has been created, you display the link to the "edit" page and the link contains the guid (http://site.addr.com/post/edit/123&key=7723eee7-b644-4f17-bf63-762228886eca) asking the user to store the link somehow to be able to edit their data
- you ask the user for her e-mail and you send them the "edit link" http://site.addr.com/post/edit/123&key=7723eee7-b644-4f17-bf63-762228886eca